# Outlook web Add-in not working in Outlook 2013 desktop client

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

We have developed an **Outlook Web Addin** that works with all major platforms such as **Office 365**, **Outlook 2019** and **Outlook 2016**. We are getting issues with only **Outlook 2013**.

When we submit this app to be **Microsoft** for publishing on **AppSource**. We get validation error saying that the solution doesn't work in `Outlook 2013`.

Below is the code that we use on every page. It seems that  `Office.initialize` method is not fired by `office.js` in `Outlook 2013`. And that's why the application doesn't hide the loading screen and gets rejected by the **Microsoft**.

```
<script>
    Office.initialize = function () {
        $(function () {
            // HideLoading();
        });
    };
</script>
```

We don't have any Outlook 2013 client, at our end.  How can we verify that why `Office.initialize` is not getting fired.

**Note:** We developed the Addin using `ASP.NET MVC 5` and we are using `office.js` from CDN `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js`

Please let us know if we need to share the Manifest XML URL?

Comment: What is your version number of Office and Outlook? Steps to attach a debugger to see if Office.initialize is called can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: What requirement set does your add-in support? Depending on the requirement set, you may exclude support for Outlook 2013.

Comment: Actually, We were using pinnable tasks and those are not supported in 2013. So We wrapped the code of making the pane pinnable in a condition i.e. if(Office.context && Office.context.mailbox && Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync) and submitted to app to Microsoft for review again. Let's see what happens.